# Arduino I2C communication not receiving sent bytes completely

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, i2c, arduino-c++

I'm trying the I2C protocol between Arduinos and I got it to work. I am still missing the 4th sensor reading on the master arduino but on the slave I read it. Also, sometimes when starting the arduinos I get these symbols. Then they disappear. Is this just a miss use of my loop on the slave or how I'm using the Wire library?

```
S_1, 22.46
S_2, 15.14
����������
S_1, 21.97
S_2, 10.25
����������
```

Master Arduino

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Begin I2C communication protocol
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop() {
  char buffer[64];
  Wire.requestFrom(1,sizeof(buffer));

  while (Wire.available()){
    char c = Wire.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

Master Output

```
S_1, 21.97
S_2, 7.32
S_3, 21.48

S_1, 21.97
S_2, 7.32
S_3, 21.48
```

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

String Sensors[4] = {"A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"};
String logData;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(1);
  Wire.onRequest(loop);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int reading = analogRead(A0 + i);
    float voltage = reading * (5000 / 1024.0);
    float temp = voltage / 10;
    logData = "S_" + String(i + 1) + ", " + String(temp) + "\n";
    Serial.print(logData);
    Wire.write(logData.c_str());
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Slave Output

```
S_1, 22.95
S_2, 8.30
S_3, 21.97
S_4, 492.68
```

The master should receive the readings from A0 to A 3. Just like the slave output.

Comment: I used the Wire some years ago, but you have some errors in your code: (1) A0+i is not correct, as you can't be sure at 100% that A1 is on the next pin. You should use an array with the pins A0,A1,... Remember that A4 and A5 is often used for the SDL/SDA! `Wire.onRequest`  set to loop is really bad! In this way, when you receive something on the wire, loop is called twice! From mainloop and from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Some help for your code:

**Do not use A0 + j**
Every Arduino has another pin mapping. Even if it works, this can give you some  errors on some boards.
Use an array and set every pin:

```
uint8_t Sensors[4] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
int reading = analogRead(Sensors[i]);
```

**Do not use int**
int has a different size on each platform. It is not well defined and the max number on Arduino it is typically 32,767. Please use `int16_t`. On your code, you are multiplying it with a big number, so you could have 4096 * 5000 = 20'480'000.
It would be better if you use bigger variables and unsigned (even if it would work in your example):

```
uint32_t reading = analogRead(Sensors[i]);
float voltage = reading * (5000 / 1024.0);
```

**The error in your code**
The error is probably in the `Wire.onRequest(loop);` call. You set a function to call, when the slave is answering. In this way, when you send some data from master on the loop, Wire will call this function too. So the function is executed twice. You do not need `onRequest` on your example, so remove it and it should work.